# Issue with using TestContext.Datarow in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, mstest, data-driven-tests

This is my first question here and I am hoping I will be able to receive some help.

To preface what I am trying to do is run a Data Driven test script using MSTest on VSCode.

When I attempt to get the value from the file by using

```
string webSiteTwo = TestContext.DataRow["Website"];
```

`DataRow` is showing an error saying:

> '`TestContext`' does not contain a definition for '`DataRow`' and no
>   extension method '`DataRow`' accepting a first argument of type
>   '`TestContext`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

When looking online the `DataRow` object seems to come from `System.Data` so I added using `System.Data` to my program to see if that settled it, but that did not work. I then tried to add using `System.Data.Datarow` to see if that worked but it seems that I do not have the assemblies for that.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this problem and if they have how did they fix it.

I am using a Macbook Pro, with VSCode 1.20.1, C#

```
.csproj file includes these References.

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.2.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.10.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Appium.WebDriver" Version="3.0.0.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0"/>
```

I have set up both the Datasource and

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;
public TestContext TestContext
{
       get { return testContextInstance; }
       set { testContextInstance = value; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?
The .Net Core version of the adapter does not support DataSource yet.
https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the correct Namespace is:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

Take a look here: [TestContext.DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.datarow.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response I guess I should have included a list of what I am using.
    `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using Appium.Interfaces;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.iOS;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data;`